# dnspython dynamic update PeerBadKey

Tags: python, dns, dnspython, bind9

I'm working with dnspython attempting to perform updates against a BIND9 server, however I keep getting a Bad Key response (“tsig verify failure (BADKEY)”) - when I use nsupdate the key works just fine.  Is there anyone  who has successfully implemented dnspython to perform dynamic updates against BIND DNS?

Here is a GIST with all code and errors:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0afc800ef0615aa7c1219ec25c032eef

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to use the keyalgorithm parameter to the update.Update function, as well as import the specific algorithm from the dns.tsig module

```
from dns import query, update, tsigkeyring
from dns.tsig import HMAC_SHA256

key='EQSVvuA/KMAa/0ugdBBLqjxgP+o5rI7y8JoJbOICpJM='
bindhost='192.168.56.10'
ip='192.168.56.10'

keyring = tsigkeyring.from_text({
    'test.local' : key
    })

update = update.Update('test.local.', keyring=keyring, keyalgorithm=HMAC_SHA256)
update.replace('abc', 300, 'A', ip)

response = query.tcp(update, bindhost, timeout=10)
```

Comment: That you had to import the algorithm, is probably because of how you did the previous imports. This is how I did the same - but without that extra import: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47985135/1399595